# Ojet Row reordering shows the entire table selection when dragging the single row

Tags: oracle-jet

I am using oj table with row reordering. When I try to drag and drop the row instead of dragging the singe row it looks like dragging the entire table

Expected result:
[image]

But when I try to drag it looks like one below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by setting background color of table body to none which was set in override.css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried the sample code, which is available in the OJET cookbook section. which is trying to drag a row from one source table to another. you can see in cookbook that

```
dnd.drag.rows.data-types='["application/ojtablerows+json"]',
dnd.drag.rows.drag-start="[[handleDragStart]]",
dnd.drag.rows.drag-end="[[handleDragEnd]]"
```

these are defined in source table and

```
dnd.drop.rows.data-types='["application/ojtablerows+json"]',
dnd.drop.rows.drop="[[handleDropRows]]"
```

These are defined in the target table. if you want to drag a row from same table and drop it in same table only, you have to write

```
dnd.drop.rows.data-types='["application/ojtablerows+json"]',
dnd.drop.rows.drop='[[handleDropRows]]'
```

these lines. then you have only defined the "handleDropRows" function. which will solve your problem.